# sequelize keeps showing same message again and again with no errors

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

[image: terminal window]

Sequelize keeps showing "Loaded configuration file "config\config.json".
Using environment "development"." after every command.

Edit: solved by updating all dependencies to the latest version

```
npm i sequelize@latest pg@latest pg-hstore@latest
```

Comment: If you've found a solution please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by updating dependencies

```
npm i sequelize@latest pg@latest pg-hstore@latest
```